# If the probability of a single point of a continuous distribution is zero, why can I obtain density values from the normal?

Tags: probability, statistics

I was hoping to clarify a possibly wrong notion I have. I understand that for a continuous distribution, say the normal, the probability of a single point, say 0, has zero probability. However, if I plug into the standard normal density, I get 0.3989423 in R. Does anyone know what part I am missing here? Thanks.

Comment: If $f$ is the probability density function, then $f(x)$ is *not* the probability that the random variable takes value $x$.

Comment: Density is not a probability. The density at $0$ being about $0.3989$ means that if $h$ is a quite small positive number, then $\Pr(0\le Z\le h)\approx 0.3989h$.  There are many examples of densities greater than $1$ on some interval.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the probability that your standard normal take a value in a small interval around $0$, say $(-0.0005,0.0005]$.  In R this is

```
> pnorm(0+0.0005) - pnorm(0-0.0005)
[1] 0.0003989423
```

This is close to the density at $0$ multiplied by the length of the interval

```
> dnorm(0) * 0.001
[1] 0.0003989423
```

If the interval shrinks towards zero then the probability will also shrinks towards zero, so you might say that the probability of being exactly $0$ (or any other given value) is zero.

The key point to remember is that the density of a continuous random variable is not a probability, but is the derivative of the cumulative probability function, in a similar way to instantaneous velocity not being a distance.